# C# Cancel task on event

Tags: c#, .net, cancellation

Is it possible to cancel task with Cancellation Token without polling?
The problem is that function wrapped in task is too resource intensive for the processor and RAM so I need to stop it and not stop waiting for task to finish.

Current code:

```
Task.Run(() => 
{
    while(true)
    {
        token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        RenderDoc();
    }
}, token);
```

Is it possible to avoid `while` loop for polling token status and cancel current task and all it's children without requesting token status every time?

Like:

```
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
var token = cts.Token;
token.Register(() => NotifyCancel());
void Foo()
{
    Task.Run(() => 
    {
        RenderDoc();
    }, token);
}

void Cancel()
{
   //handle event here

   //stop task
   cts.Cancel();
}
```

The problem is that when I register a callback for a token
and call `cts.Cancel();` task continues to execute.

Comment: Checking if cancellation was requested at logical points in your code is correct. You probably want to see https://stackoverflow.com/q/13794229/11683, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/how-to-listen-for-cancellation-requests-by-polling and https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/10/05/how-do-i-cancel-non-cancelable-async-operations/.

Comment: This one is also worth a look https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/csharpfaq/2010/07/19/parallel-programming-task-cancellation/

Comment: Well, all linked solutions doesn't stop currently executing tasks, they are just calling delegates but task continues to execute in background (as far as I've tested it right).